# Process JSON data by using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, regex

I am trying to process some JSON data. Basically my JSON file have two objects Name and ID.
Is there a chance to extract only some data using for example RegExp from all objects?

Here is a code of js script:

```
$.getJSON('list.json',function(data){
var output = '<ol>';  
$.each(data, function(key,val){
  output += '<li id="'+val.ID+ '">'+ val.Name + '</li>';
});
output += '</ol>';
$('#update').html(output);
});
```

Part of JSON data:

```
{

    "Name": "Forrest.Gump.1994.MULTi.1080p.AMZN.WEB-DL.DDP5.1.H264-Ao",
    "ID": "SMwIkBoC2blXeWnBa9Hjge9YPs90"

},
{

    "Name": "Point.Blank.2019.MULTi.1080p.NF.WEB-DL.DDP5.1.x264-Ao",
    "ID": "OZI4mOuBXuJ7b89FLgXJoozyhHe9"

},
{

    "Name": "The.Incredible.Hulk.2008.MULTi.2160p.UHD.BluRay.REMUX.HDR.HEVC.DTS-HD.MA.7.1",
    "ID": "jZzR4_B_vjm593cYKR7j97XAMv6d"

},
```

I wish to extract a year from Name as seperate object and put it in HTML li tag. Something like:

```
output += '<li id="'+val.ID+ '">'+ val.Name + ' ' + val.Name[YEAR ONLY from Name] +'</li>';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Given the format of the string contained in `Name` there's no 100% reliable way to detect the year. The closest method you could use would be to use a Regex to pull out the first 4 digit number, but even that would be broken if the film name has a number in it, eg. `2001:.A.Space.Oddysey.1968.MULTi...`. I would strongly suggest you instead amend the JSON to return the year in a separate property. Any other solution is a brittle hack. The same goes for the format, resolution and codec data.

Comment: If at all possible, change your service to return the data at a lower level so your frontend does not have to deconstruct it.  It's a common programming pattern, that if you find yourself deconstructing your data often, it is not at the correct granular level.